# Get a resource using getResource()

Tags: java, resources, getresource

I need to get a resource image file in a java project. What I'm doing is:

```
URL url = TestGameTable.class.getClass().
          getClassLoader().getResource("unibo.lsb.res/dice.jpg");
```

The directory structure is the following:

```
unibo/
  lsb/
    res/
      dice.jpg
    test/
    ..../ /* other packages */
```

The fact is that I always get as the file doesn't exist. I have tried many different paths, but I couldn't solve the issue.
Any hint?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

```
TestGameTable.class.getResource("/unibo/lsb/res/dice.jpg");
```

- leading slash to denote the root of the classpath
- slashes instead of dots in the path
- you can call `getResource()` directly on the class.

Comment: Just be aware that `Class#getResource` and `ClassLoader#getResource` are using different strategies to map the name to a location. LucaB's example actually uses the ClassLoader from Class<java.lang.Class> (`SomeClass.class.getClass()`), but that's probably a mistake and not on purpose.

Comment: @jambjo yes, I assumed it's a mistake.

Comment: It is a mistake. Thanks for the hint

Comment: I tested it but this returned null. I wrote like that: `MyClass.class.getResource("/WebContent/WEB-INF/xsd/MyXsd.xsd")`. any mistake I did?

Answer (score 24):

Instead of explicitly writing the class name you could use

```
this.getClass().getResource("/unibo/lsb/res/dice.jpg");
```

Comment: Or just `getClass()` without `this`.

Comment: This is assuming you are not within a static context.

Answer (score 10):

if you are calling from `static` method, use :

```
TestGameTable.class.getClassLoader().getResource("dice.jpg");
```

Comment: what about if calling other than static method?

Answer (score 4):

One thing to keep in mind is that the relevant path here is the path relative to the file system location of your class... in your case TestGameTable.**class**.  It is not related to the location of the TestGameTable.**java** file.
I left a more detailed answer here...  [where is resource actually located](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41781868/7394973)

Comment: The `.class` file is not necessarily stored in the file system directly. It may also be part of a `.jar` file...

Comment: I remarked that `TestGameTable.class.getClassLoader().getResource("dice.jpg");` worked in packaged App/jar but `getClass().getResource("/unibo/lsb/res/dice.jpg");` didn't work.