# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null

Tags: java

I'm participating in this Mini Ludum Dare #49

I've got my code done but I've got one problem (well a few) when running and compiling.

I am getting this output in the console
"

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.cmnatic.mld.GameState.IntroState.init(IntroState.java:31)
    at com.cmnatic.mld.Manager.GameStateManager.setState(GameStateManager.java:46)
    at com.cmnatic.mld.Manager.GameStateManager.<init>(GameStateManager.java:36)
    at com.cmnatic.mld.Main.GamePanel.init(GamePanel.java:95)
    at com.cmnatic.mld.Main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:59)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

"
Now, I can give a long list of all the class files' code.

(com.cmnatic.mld.GameState.IntroState) at com.cmnatic.mld.GameState.IntroState.init(IntroState.java:31))

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.cmnatic.mld.Main.GamePanel;
import com.cmnatic.mld.Manager.GameStateManager;
import com.cmnatic.mld.Manager.Keys;

public class IntroState extends GameState {

    private BufferedImage logo;

    private int alpha;
    private int ticks;

    private final int FADE_IN = 60;
    private final int LENGTH = 60;
    private final int FADE_OUT = 60;

    public IntroState(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
    }

    public void init() {
        ticks = 0;
        try {
            logo = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("res/Logo/logo.gif"));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void update() {
        handleInput();
        ticks++;
        if(ticks < FADE_IN) {
            alpha = (int) (255 - 255 * (1.0 * ticks / FADE_IN));
            if(alpha < 0) alpha = 0;
        }
        if(ticks > FADE_IN + LENGTH) {
            alpha = (int) (255 * (1.0 * ticks - FADE_IN - LENGTH) / FADE_OUT);
            if(alpha > 255) alpha = 255;
        }
        if(ticks > FADE_IN + LENGTH + FADE_OUT) {
            gsm.setState(GameStateManager.MENU);
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GamePanel.WIDTH, GamePanel.HEIGHT2);
        g.drawImage(logo, 0, 0, GamePanel.WIDTH, GamePanel.HEIGHT2, null);
        g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, alpha));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GamePanel.WIDTH, GamePanel.HEIGHT2);
    }

    public void handleInput() {
        if(Keys.isPressed(Keys.ENTER)) {
            gsm.setState(GameStateManager.MENU);
        }
    }

}
```

(at com.cmnatic.mld.Manager.GameStateManager.setState(GameStateManager.java:46)
at com.cmnatic.mld.Manager.GameStateManager.(GameStateManager.java:36)

```
package com.cmnatic.mld.GameState;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import com.cmnatic.mld.Manager.GameStateManager;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;


public abstract class GameState {

    protected GameStateManager gsm;

    public GameState(GameStateManager gsm) {
        this.gsm = gsm;
    }

    public abstract void init();
    public abstract void update();
    public abstract void draw(Graphics2D g);
    public abstract void handleInput();

}
```

at com.cmnatic.mld.Main.GamePanel.init(GamePanel.java:95)
    at com.cmnatic.mld.Main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:59)

```
package com.cmnatic.mld.Main;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.cmnatic.mld.Manager.GameStateManager;
import com.cmnatic.mld.Manager.Keys;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener {

    // dimensions
    // HEIGHT is the playing area size
    // HEIGHT2 includes the bottom window
    public static final int WIDTH = 128;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 128;
    public static final int HEIGHT2 = HEIGHT + 16;
    public static final int SCALE = 3;

    // game loop stuff
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;
    private final int FPS = 30;
    private final int TARGET_TIME = 1000 / FPS;

    // drawing stuff
    private BufferedImage image;
    private Graphics2D g;

    // game state manager
    private GameStateManager gsm;

    // constructor
    public GamePanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT2 * SCALE));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
    }

    // ready to display
    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        if(thread == null) {
            addKeyListener(this);
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    // run new thread
    public void run() {

        init();

        long start;
        long elapsed;
        long wait;

        // game loop
        while(running) {

            start = System.nanoTime();

            update();
            draw();
            drawToScreen();

            elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;

            wait = TARGET_TIME - elapsed / 1000000;
            if(wait < 0) wait = TARGET_TIME;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(wait);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    // initializes fields
    private void init() {
        running = true;
        image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT2, 1);
        g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        gsm = new GameStateManager();
    }

    // updates game
    private void update() {
        gsm.update();
        Keys.update();
    }

    // draws game
    private void draw() {
        gsm.draw(g);
    }

    // copy buffer to screen
    private void drawToScreen() {
        Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT2 * SCALE, null);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    // key event
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent key) {}
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {
        Keys.keySet(key.getKeyCode(), true);
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key) {
        Keys.keySet(key.getKeyCode(), false);
    }

}
```

at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Sorry for the really long post, but that's the code that's related to the problem.

I'm really tired so I'll sleep for a few hours and check back :)

Thanks guys,

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you have the following folder structure (use the lowercase convention)

```
project
  | -- src
  | -- resources
  |       | -- logo
  |             | -- logo.gif
```

modify your `IntroState.init()` to

```
try {
    logo = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/logo/logo.gif"));
}
```

Note the `/` before `resources`. This code works perfectly. Just tested with a simple application.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. Unfortunately, this doesn't fix the problem.
:<

Comment: Where the `res` folder is located? The problem seems to be that `res/Logo/logo.gif` was not found.

Comment: Jeah it does not find the gif that's all, try to include the name of your directory TestGameTable.class.getResource("/my/app/res/Logo/logo.gif"); => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593154/get-a-resource-using-getresource

Comment: @MarcelBlanck 
The res folder ("Resource") is located within the project, It is detected in eclipse.

Also, here is a picture (gyazo link)
http://gyazo.com/6e265a68c59cf61d8e422cfd87231690
(project location)

http://gyazo.com/d912b516bd08cb7c8148678699d766fe
(Eclipse Project folder)

Also, my code is this "logo = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Logo/logo.gif"));"

Sorry guys :/

(

Comment: So, why are you using `res` if your folder is called `Resources`? Also  your code won't work if your folder `Resources` is not in your classpath. Try to add the `Resources` folder to your classpath and change your code to `logo = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Resources/Logo/logo.gif"));`

Comment: Yes that would have been my next question too - What about "/Resources/Logo/logo.gif"

Comment: @MarcelBlanck
Hey guys, I'm sorry. I'm being a right idiot.

I've added the Resources folder to my classpath, deleted res and added the suggest code.

Still no luck, :<

Comment: @user3335689 I've just tested the code and it works perfectly. Please, take a look at my updated answer. I've included more information about the required folder structure. If you follow exactly that, I guarantee 100% that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getClass().getResourceAsStream("res/Logo/logo.gif")` returns `null`. So, when you pass it as the first argument of `ImageIO.read()`, it will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, as said in [`ImageIO` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29):

> **Throws:**
>
> ```
> IllegalArgumentException - if input is null.
> ```

According to the [`Class` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), `getResourceAsStream()` returns `null` when it can't find the ressource:

> **Returns:**
>
> ```
> A InputStream object or null if no resource with this name is found
> ```

So, the problem is that `res/Logo/logo.gif` cannot be found.

Here is what you have to check:

- does the file exists ?
- is it the correct path ?
- is the case correct ?
- do you miss a "/" at the beginning of the path (thus making it relative instead of absolute) ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, 3 years to late, but I got the same problem and also none of the answers worked.
So I tried this and now it's working fine (so if anyone is searching for this):

*Refresh the resouces folder in the Eclipse package explorer!*

Now the image should show up in the explorer and then there is no more exception.