# Locate a folder in a maven project java when running from jar throgh class.getClassLoader().getResource(""); method

Tags: java, maven, classloader

We are in a problem in which we are reading a folder inside a project 
For that we have kept the folder inside the resource folder

> src\main\resource\plugins

we need to find the path of the plugin folder inside the resource folder . 
When running from eclipse below code is working but when the same is invoked with jar then not able to run

```
String path =  XYZClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("plugins").getFile();
```

it is able to find the path in eclipse but when running fron jar it not able to recognize it and when i print the path as coming on console

D:/Workarea/text/lib/xyx-3.2.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/plugins

Comment: Does replacing `plugins` with `/plugins` work?  Refer to [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593154/get-a-resource-using-getresource) discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the `process-resources` [life cycle phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) the content which is located in `src/main/resources` will be copied into `target/classes` folder. The result is that the resource is accessible under `/plugins` casae the `/`  is the root folder of the jar which in result will be packaged later.