# NullPointerException on ClassLoader.getResource()

Tags: java, file, jar, nullpointerexception

i'm working on a little project and i need to move a file from the application JAR to another location outside the JAR.

This is how my JAR file looks like:

```
MyApp.JAR
   |- META-INF
       |- MANIFEST.MF
   |- files
       |- myFile.exe
   |- MainClass.class
```

What i'd like to do is move `myFile.exe` to `C:\\` (for example).
So in the `MainClass` i tried with:

```
23. Path path = Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/files/myFile.exe").toURI());
24. byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);

25. FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\myFile.exe");
26. fos.write(b);
27. fos.close();
```

After running my application i get a `NullPointerException`, here's it:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MainClass.<init>(MainClass.java:23)
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:66)
```

(Line 66 is where i call the constructor with `new MainClass();`)

I know the `NPE` is probably thrown because `myFile.exe` cannot be found,  but i can't figure out why...
When i open the JAR i can see the `files` folder with the `exe` inside.
Maybe i'm accessing the file in a wrong way? 
I tried many other ways that i found here on StackOverflow but nothing works...

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: Maybe you can split line 23 into multiple assignments line-by-line, that way it will be visible what returns `null`?

Comment: The correct path is `files/myFile.exe`, without leading slash. But you should just read bytes from the InputStream returned by `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("files/myFile.exe")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here you are taking too many intermediate clunky steps, because the standard Java APIs don't allow you to do it immediately. I recommend you using [`IOUtils.copy`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)) to copy the bytes over:

```
try(InputStream resourceStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/files/myFile.exe");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\myFile.exe"))
{
    IOUtils.copy(resourceStream, fos);
} // optionally, catch IOException here (or declare it to be thrown)
```

If you need assistance with the URL provided to `getResourceAsStream()`, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2593175/4464702).

Answer (score 0):

You are using an absolute path: you should be using `("files/myFiles.exe")` iso `("/files/myFiles.exe")`