# Java URL returning null

Tags: java, url

I am trying to get some files stored in my project folder. As answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593154/get-a-resource-using-getresource) I tried the following code, just before trying it 'for real':

I created a Test class, very simple:

```
public class Test
{
    public URL url;

  public Test()
  {
    url = Test.class.getResource("/src/main/resources/parseID.xsd");
  }
}
```

And then a dummy MainClass:

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        Test t = new Test();

        t.url = Test.class.getResource("/src/main/resources/parseID.xsl");

        System.out.println(t.url);
    }
}
```

This is giving a `null` display on my console. Both of the classes are in the same package. The resource is there, from the root of the project:

```
src/
 |  main/
 |   |  resources/
 |   |   |     parseID.xsd
```

Can anyone help me out ? I have trouble figuring out.

Comment: `src/main/resources` is a source folder so `parseID.xsl` is actually a resource of your project. You must access resources, that are on the classpath, through an `InputStream`.

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you !