# How do I add an image with this code?

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import java.awt.Image;

import javax.sound.midi.Patch;

import javax.swing.*;
```

*this is were the code start*

```
public class graficCar extends JComponent
{
    private ImageIcon image1=null;

private JLabel label1=null;

private ImageIcon image2=null;

private JLabel label2=null;

 graficCar(){

setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

***the problem here***

```
image1=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("4596067.png"));

   label1=new JLabel(image1);
add(label1);
}
```

**the main**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    graficCar g=new graficCar();
    g.setDebugGraphicsOptions(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    g.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException when i create the image1.

Comment: Looks like that file isn't in the right place

Comment: please describe where is the .png located. Please also add stacktrace to the question

Comment: the png in C:\Users\user\Downloads

Comment: what is stacktrace?

Comment: You could read about stacktrace even [on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, your png file is in `C:\Users\user\Downloads` folder. I bet class is somewhere else.
The problem is `getResource()` finds file in classpath by default. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) you could find details if you want to go deeper.

One solution is to put .png right next to your .java class but it's bad practice. More convenient way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593154/get-a-resource-using-getresource). The best practice is to create special folder for your resources in the project and then use relative path to it. How to do this is out of scope although it's described in many sites and in Stackoverflow too. Don't hesistate to use *Search* :)