# Java JAR file runs on local machine but missing file on others

Tags: java, ffmpeg

The JAR file consists of the ffmpeg.exe file and it can run normally on my machine without any problems. However, if I try to run it on another computer it would tell me that `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ffmpeg.exe": CreateProcess error=2,The system cannot find the file specified` from the stacktrace. The way I imported it was

```
FFMpeg ffmpeg = new FFMpeg("ffmpeg.exe");  //in res folder

...
//ffmpeg class
public FFMPEG(String ffmepgEXE) {
    this.ffmepgEXE = ffmepgEXE;
}
```

Comment: Is the res folder packaged inside the jar, or is it located in the same file as the jar? If it's inside the jar, then you need to load it as a resource, not `new FFMpeg("ffmpeg.exe");` which will attempt to lad the file from the working directory (same folder as the jar).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a resource using getResource()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593154/get-a-resource-using-getresource)

Comment: https://prnt.sc/6ms_rJqUv1tu the folder isn't there but all the files are. I tried changing the constructor to just `this.ffmepgEXE = getClass().getResource("/ffmpeg.exe").getPath();` but it's giving me the `The system cannot find the file specified` error when I try to use it

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix is you have to put `ffmpeg.exe` in the same folder with your `.jar` file.

If you want to read file from `resources` folder, you have to change this code:

```java
URL resource = Test.class.getResource("ffmpeg.exe");
String filepath = Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toFile().getAbsolutePath(); 
FFMpeg ffmpeg = new FFMpeg(filepath);
```

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that the other computer don't have access to the `ffmpeg.exe` file. I tried following that article but his dealt with readable files while I just want the file path for the `ffmpeg.exe` file

Comment: I updated the answer. Could you test it?

Comment: I'm getting a null pointer on line 3, even in my IDE