# Hello world with JavaFX Fxml Project

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Today i am Going to create Hello World Application with JavaFX Fxml project.Here is the code.
       Sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="temp.Temp">
<children>
    <Button id="button" layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
    <Label id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" prefHeight="16" prefWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Sample.java

```
package temp;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
public class Sample implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Label label;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    label.setText("Hello World!");
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}    
}
```

Temp.java

```
package temp;
import javafx.application.Appl
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Temp extends Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(Temp.class, args);
}
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    try{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e);
    }      
}
}
```

But It is Giving Error 
/Users/apple/NetBeansProjects/Temp/nbproject/jfx-impl.xml:1757: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/apple/NetBeansProjects/Temp/nbproject/jfx-impl.xml:1392: jarsigner returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: ६ seconds)

But When i Use Exception Handling it Gives Location Not Found ?
Please help

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to load Controller from `fx:controller="temp.Temp"`. This is not Your controller class, you should use `fx:controller="temp.Sample"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You also [need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343187/loading-resources-using-getclass-getresource) a leading forward slash to load package resources.  Assuming that you have Sample.fxml in the temp package, it would look like this:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/temp/Sample.fxml"));
```