# Can't find resource outside the jar

Tags: java, resourcebundle, properties-file

I am trying to read properties which is located external to the jar file of my code.using `ResourceBundle` but its unable to read the property file `locations.properties`. The property file is located under `resource` folder and both `jar` and `resource` folder are under same directory.

```
myDir

   --> myJar.jar
   --> resource
          -->locations.properties
```

I don't know whats wrong with my code below:

```
public static ResourceBundle getResourceBundle(String fileName) throws MalformedURLException{
    if (resourceBundle == null) {
        File file = new File("resource/"+fileName);
        URL[] urls = { file.toURI().toURL() };
        ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(fileName, Locale.getDefault(), loader);
    }
    return resourceBundle;
}
```

And this is how am invoking `ResourceBundle` object:

```
ResourceBundle locationBundle = null;
try {
    locationBundle = ReadPropertyUtil.getResourceBundle(propFileName);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please guide whats wrong with this code and whats the correct way of reading an external properties file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading resources using getClass().getResource()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343187/loading-resources-using-getclass-getresource)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I figured out the error myself. I was appending the fileName to the directory location `File file = new File("resource/"+fileName);` which was wrong.

All I had to do was to first get the present working directory name using

```
System.getProperties("user.dir")   //this gives me the path of my current directory
```

and passing only the directory name to file object.

```
File file = new File("resource/");
```

And then load the bundle using the specified file name.

```
resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(fileName, Locale.getDefault(), loader);
```

ResourceBundle automatically looks into the directory and loads the file specified by the `fileName`

Comment: I belive it should be System.getProperty("user.dir") instead of getProperties.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get Jar file path.
2. Get Parent folder of that file.
3. Use that path in InputStreamPath with your properties file name.

   ```
   Properties prop = new Properties();
   try {
           File jarPath=new File(YourClassNameInJar.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
           String propertiesPath=jarPath.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
           System.out.println(" propertiesPath-"+propertiesPath);
           prop.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesPath+"/resource/locations.properties"));
       } catch (IOException e1) {
           e1.printStackTrace();
       }
   ```

Comment: Using ResourceBundle?