# ImageIO in Java

Tags: java, image

I'm a second year student just starting to pick up Java. I have this bit of code and it keeps throwing the exception:

```
try
{
    masterFish = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("fish1.gif"));
} 
catch (IOException iOException)
{
    iOException.printStackTrace();
}
```

Could someone explain the `fish1.gif` part? Am I supposed to have an image called `fish1.gif` downloaded somewhere?

Comment: For that code to work you need fish1.gif somewhere on the class path at runtime.

Comment: Specifically, the `fish1.gif` should be in the same package as the class which is trying to load it. If the gif is an animated gif, then you won't want to use `ImageIO`, but instead will need to use `ImageIcon`

Comment: Can you also tell us what exception it's throwing

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I ended up making it work by putting the image in a resources folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question: [Loading resources using getClass().getResource()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343187/loading-resources-using-getclass-getresource)

The *getResource()* method of *getClass()* will attempt to find a resource using the class file (.class extension) as a reference point. Thus your file should be located at the same place the class file is. For instance if your class is com.example.MyClass, your "fish1.gif" file should be located in the directory <>/src/com/example.

It is often considered bad style to mix resources and source code, so you might want to create a directory "resources" at the root of your project, place the resources there in a suitable hierarchy, and access them in a centralized way.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely can't find "fish1.gif". Make sure when you compile your code, that "fish1.gif" is in the same directory as your "MAIN CLASS". Or instead of just "fish1.gif" you can write specifically where it is located on your hard-drive...
Example: "C:/Users/**name**/Desktop/fish1.gif".

Comment: I have it in the src file right now (I'm using Intellij). Should it be somewhere else?