# How to use getClass and getResource?

Tags: java, image, imageicon, getresource

Here's the error I am getting:

```
Using directory  file:/D:/CCSF%20Docs/CS111B/Java%20Projects/LabelDemo2.java/bin/ 
Image url is null 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source) 
    at LabelDemo2.<init>(LabelDemo2.java:23) 
    at LabelDemo2.main(LabelDemo2.java:46)
```

Could anyone tell me why I can't load the image? The java.jpg image is in `D:/CCSF%20Docs/CS111B/Java%20Projects/LabelDemo2.java/bin/`

I don't know why I am getting a null exception/error.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LabelDemo2 extends JFrame {
    private ImageIcon image1;
    private JLabel label1;
    private ImageIcon image2;
    private JLabel label2;
    private ImageIcon image3;
    private JLabel label3;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    LabelDemo2() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        System.out.println("Using directory " + getClass().getResource(""));         
        System.out.println("Image url is " + getClass().getResource("java.jpg"));         
        image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("java.jpg"));
        label1 = new JLabel(image1);
        add(label1);


        label1 = new JLabel(image1);
        add(label1);

        image2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("java.jpg"));

        label2 = new JLabel(image2);
        add(label2);

        image3 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("java.jpg"));

        label3 = new JLabel(image3);
        add(label3);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        LabelDemo2 gui = new LabelDemo2();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.pack();
        gui.setTitle("Label Demo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the image in the source folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading resources using getClass().getResource()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343187/loading-resources-using-getclass-getresource)

Comment: `getResource()` has a somewhat interesting way of specifying paths. Seen the above link for more information about it. In short, it's easiest to put the file you want to read in your source folder/in your project and specify the path as an absolute path where "/" stands for the source folder.

Comment: can you try with `ClassPathResource fileReference = new ClassPathResource(filename);` then `fileReference.getInputStream()`

Answer (score 0):

If the `image` is in your source folder, then you do like below to read the `Image`

```
getClass().getResource("/java.jpg")
```

Just put `/` or `\\`

If it is outside of your source folder, then you can read it by `InputStream` with Absolute path

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(path);
```

OR

```
ClassPathResource fileReference = new ClassPathResource(filename);  
InputStream in = fileReference.getInputStream();
```

OR

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

Further reading [Different ways of loading a file as an InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676250/different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream)